# Getting 404 not found when I do sudo update Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

I am getting the following error when I try to update the apt repository in Ubuntu Server 22.04

```
channaveer@channaveer:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Err:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.124 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I remove all these error when I do `sudo apt update`

Following is my `**/etc/apt/sources.list**`

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get files from old-releases? Or from this one? http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release

Comment: Remove these entries from the sources list and then try. BTW Impish is 21.10.

Comment: @David while installing MongoDB I copied the latest code from MongoDB doc and this issue started.

Comment: @David can you please help how can I remove these entries

Comment: @David this path /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal.

Edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list and remove the invalid entries for impish and old-release.

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Save the file and retry apt upgrade.

Comment: I removed all the files and added from other ubuntu server. But still I get the same **impish-security** issue. Tried even clearing cache and other stuff but didnt work out. Any help is really appriciated

Comment: Did youy remove this one? Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease

Comment: By the way if the answer works please accept it. Up vote and accept are different .